# Hotkeys for HOMM-VI / Heroes 6

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

I know that keyboard commands can be found in: Settings -> Options -> Hotkeys

Is there a cheat-sheet in-game? ready read-me file? any hotkeys cheat-sheets out there?